# Django - authenticate method error. The view home.views.loginAdmin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie to Django. I'm stuck at one thing that, my login authenticate method return None. I've tried my best to search and try to solve this but i didn't find my problem solution.
In **Following First Code Sample From Which I Got Error**,

`def loginAdmin(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username'],
    password = request.POST['password'],
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
      auth.login(request, user)  
      return redirect('/admin-dashboard')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'invalid')
else:
    return HttpResponse('No')
    #  return render(request,'login.html') `
```

I'm getting value of form and using variable in authenticate method but its giving me that error. But in **Following Second Code Sample That Execute Successfully**
`
def loginAdmin(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username'],
    password = request.POST['password'],
    user = auth.authenticate(username = 'user1', password = 'pass123')
    if user is not None:
      auth.login(request, user)  
      return redirect('/admin-dashboard')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'invalid')
else:
    return HttpResponse('No')
    #  return render(request,'login.html')
```

` if, I used hard coded value in authenticate method that i know saved in database username and password, then it will execute successful. I've debug form username and password They are coming.
I tried to elaborate my problem. Please guide me how to solve this.
Thank You.
[Screen Shot 1 Link: Having error in This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXpHo.png)
[Screen Shot 2 Link: But No error if Hard Coded Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox5CV.png)

Comment: Can you try adding logs and check the value `username` and `password` during the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the trailing commas from the username and password.

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
```

When you use a comma like this: `elem = 2,` in Python, you make it a tuple `(2,)`, instead of a string that the authenticate function in your code requires.

Answer (score 0):

```
def loginAdmin(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
      if user is not None:
         auth.login(request, user)  
         return redirect('/admin-dashboard')
      else:
        messages.info(request, 'invalid')
        return redirect('/login')
  else:
      return HttpResponse('No')
```

Or You Can Write Like This:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
def loginAdmin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Welcome Back')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin-dashboard'))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin-dashboard'))
        return render(request, 'dashboard/login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.